# How to add a documentation to my methods and classes in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to add a documentation for each method and class I write in android studio like in the 
[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSMu3.png) when press CTRL+Q on method. How can I do that?

Comment: Just add javadoc to your code.. Android Studio will start to show those popups for you code..

Comment: Answers do not belong in the question; I've rolled back your latest edit. If you have solved the problem, please post an answer below. ([Yes, you can answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).) To make a good answer, you should show an example of *how* you added JavaDoc to one of your methods.